# NancyFX PlatformNotSupportedException when NancyHost.Start()

Tags: c#, .net, nancy

For some reason my Nancy setup stopped working
This is how I start Nancy Host:

```
string uriString = @"http://localhost:";
uriString += Port.ToString();
uriString += "/";

try
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Host.Start({uriString})");

   HostConfiguration hostConfigs = new HostConfiguration();
   hostConfigs.UrlReservations.CreateAutomatically = true;

   Uri uri = new Uri(uriString);
   var host = new NancyHost(hostConfigs, uri);
   host.Start();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine("WWW NOT Started : " + ex);
}
```

But now whenever I do `host.Start();` I get the following exception :

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on
>   this platform.
>           at System.Net.HttpListener..ctor()
>           at Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost.TryStartListener()
>           at Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost.StartListener()
>           at Nancy.Hosting.Self.NancyHost.Start()

Please help. I referenced Nancy 1.4.4 & Nancy.Hosting.Self 1.4.1

Comment: So which platform is that? Which operating system?

Comment: @Evk it's on Windows Server 2008, it works some weeks back when I set it up.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem on my local machine, running an unchanged, well-established Nancy program.  No idea why this started, but would love to hear an answer.